# Modify dynamically added elements in FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I modify dynamically added elements in FlowLayoutPanel?

I create the label and add it to the panel.

```
`for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
Label nlabel = new Label();
nlabel.text = "Label no."+i.toString();
nlabel.name = "label"+i.toString();
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(nlabel);.
}`
```

After creating and adding I want to refer to the element "i". 
The panel does not have a method    `FlowLayoutPanel.getItem(int index)` ;(

How to do it?

Thx for ans.

Comment: Set a name for them when adding and then find them by name.  for example `FlowLayoutPanel.Controls["label1"]`

Comment: First sane solution is to no lose the object references, store it in a `List<Label>`.  Backup plan is to find it back with `(Label)this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls["label"+i.ToString()]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like all controls, the `FlowLayoutPanel` has a `Controls` collection property, which you can index by ordinal or by name.

Comment: @MichałHanusek when you find a post that answers your question, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647) it by click on check mark near the answer.